# Are there any ios-framework integration tools available?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I am working on a cocoa touch dynamic framework. To integrate this framework in an ios app the user needs to:

1. add 2-3 user defined keys in xcode's build settings
2. add a couple of run script phases in the app
3. add a preprocessing macro in xcode's build settings
4. add a path in "Header search paths" in xcode's build settings

Now, I want to automate all these steps for the user so that any app can integrate my framework in 1 step.
Is there a tool which can be used to create an installer for my framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of available dependency managers:

1. [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)
2. [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage)

For example: This is [documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html) for cocoapods.